# css transforms of image slices not working

Tags: html, css

**After careful examination, redoing multiple times, I determined this is a CSS bug. It's produced in Chrome and IE. Reported as [#718561](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718561&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=).**

**Essentially, if an image is sliced into more than 10 rows and more than 3 columns, with each slice transformed (scale, skew, translate, etc.), only 3 columns will transform. The remaining slices are rendered as multiple copies of the original image.**

Original question:

This seems to get asked a lot, but I can't find a reference to this particular version of the problem: my CSS just doesn't want to work. It slices an image into slabs then scales or skews each. I've done it a few times, and it works, but this new version doesn't. Here'a an example of CSS that worked:

```
  div #first{
  margin-top: 45px;
  position:absolute;
clip: rect(0, 27px, 5px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-6deg) translate(0px,-21px) ; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-6deg) translate(0px,-21px) ; /* Chrome, 
Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-6deg) translate(0px,-21px) ;
}

div #firstsecond{
  margin-top: 45px;
  position:absolute;
clip: rect(0, 112px, 5px, 27px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(21deg) translate(-40px,0px) ; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(21deg) translate(-40px,0px) ; /* Chrome, 
Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(21deg) translate(-40px,0px) ;
}

div #firstthird{
  margin-top: 45px;
  position:absolute;
clip: rect(0, 175px, 5px, 112px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(21deg) translate(-45px,0px) ; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(21deg) translate(-45px,0px) ; /* Chrome, 
Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(21deg) translate(-45px,0px) ;
}
```

The HTML with this is:

```
                         <div id="first"> <img src="D.jpg"/></div>
                         <div id="firstsecond"> <img src="D.jpg"/></div>
                         <div id="firstthird"> <img src="D.jpg"/></div>
                         <div id="second"> <img src="D.jpg"/></div>
```

Now the CSS that doesn't work:

```
div #firstone{
         margin-top: 25px;
         position:absolute; 
clip: rect(0px,  52px, 12px, 0px);
         -ms-transform:translate(0px, -8px);
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px, -8px);
     transform:translate(0px, -8px);
    }

div #onetwo{
     margin-top: 25px;
     position:absolute; 
clip: rect(12px, 52px, 24px, 0px);
     -ms-transform:translate(0px, -7px);
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px, -7px);
     transform:translate(0px, -7px);
    }

div #onethree{
     margin-top: 25px;
     position:absolute;
clip: rect(24px, 52px, 36px, 0px);
     -ms-transform:translate(0px, -6px);
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px, -6px);
     transform:translate(0px, -6px);
}
```

The HTML for this:

```
                        <div id="firstone"> <img src="Z.jpg"/></div>
                        <div id="onetwo"> <img src="Z.jpg"/></div>
                        <div id="onethree"> <img src="Z.jpg"/></div>
```

Why doesn't the second unit work? The funny thing is the second unit is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the div before div #first.
The problem is the space between the div and ID.

Like this: `#first{}`

Comment: I found that the problem has something to do with the order in which the divs are listed in the HTML. There are 76 divs, that slice an image in 4 columns of 19 row slabs each. If I reorder the HTML list so that it's second column, then first, then fourth, then third, it renders everything but the fourth column. If I just don't include the fourth column, nothing transforms. If I put the first column before the second, only the second column transforms. I've tried all possible column orders. What I haven't down is rearrange HTML within the columns, that is, put row 19 first, then 18, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how stack context can impact CSS transforms. I understand they can effect visibility, since transformed elements become related by z-axis positions. But one column of transforms, the last one, isn't transformed. It's visible, not in the correct location, and not transformed

I've tried adjusting z values directly, no avail. Since it's the last column of effects on the image, I made sure that transformed elements didn't overflow boundaries. I can get 3 of 4 columns transformed if my HTML reorders divs so 4th column comes before 3rd. Leave 4th out, nothing transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rnb78o6d/) fiddle. Your css need to change a bit. Don't give space between `div #id` use `div#id` instead

**CSS:**

```
div#firstone{
         margin-top: 25px;
         position:absolute; 
clip: rect(0px,  52px, 12px, 0px);
         -ms-transform:translate(0px, -8px);
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px, -8px);
     transform:translate(0px, -8px);
    }

div#onetwo{
     margin-top: 25px;
     position:absolute; 
clip: rect(12px, 52px, 24px, 0px);
     -ms-transform:translate(0px, -7px);
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px, -7px);
     transform:translate(0px, -7px);
    }

div#onethree{
     margin-top: 25px;
     position:absolute;
clip: rect(24px, 52px, 36px, 0px);
     -ms-transform:translate(0px, -6px);
      -webkit-transform:translate(0px, -6px);
     transform:translate(0px, -6px);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your idea, and did so, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a CSS bug. I reported it as [718561](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718561&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=).

The versions that work have three (3) columns of transforms, or limited number of rows. I want to slice an image into 19 rows of 4 columns. Only 3 columns will transform, or only 6 or 8 rows.

I went over everything, but it's as if there's a wall after which CSS transforms don't operate.